# Remove global css file from a particular page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have globally installed bootstrap.css in my project `Bootstrap v2.3.2`.
Is there a way through which I can remove this from a particular page
OR
Overwrite this CSS with a newer version of bootstrap on the particular page ONLY?

The project is made of `kendo-asp.net-mvc`.

Comment: Comment out its line on that specific file

Comment: @LelioFaieta I's globally installed in the main file. So, how can I comment it in a particular file?

Answer (score 1):

You simply can overwrite the `ink rel:..` reference by adding the link of the newer version or if you don‘t need Bootstrap on one particular site, you can just delete the reference.

For example:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"
```

You can imply a newer or older version by editing the `href` link from above.
I hope it was useful